# ITopologicalOperator simplify takes more time

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects

The objective is to cut the polygon where the lines are intersect. The polygon has 183182 vertices and taking more time while using simply method so process time is increased very huge. Please suggest the best process to cut the polygon.

```
ITopologicalOperator2 pTopologicalOperator = PolygonFeature.Shape as ITopologicalOperator2;

pTopologicalOperator.IsKnownSimple_2 = false;
pTopologicalOperator.Simplify();

IFeatureEdit featureEdit = PolygonFeature as IFeatureEdit;
ISet newFeaturesSet = featureEdit.Split(NewPolyline);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you know your feature is good you shouldn't need to simplify it, it is only if the *simplicity* of the feature is unknown or in doubt that it would need to be simplified. A repair geometry geoprocessing task will fix features efficiently.

**DO NOT USE IFeature.Shape, use IFeature.ShapeCopy**, Shape *can* have undesired side effects as it's still *owned* by the feature, ShapeCopy no longer has a link to the feature and is *owned* by the process.

ITopologicalOperator goes up to 6 (ITopologicalOperator6), consider using a newer version as it's bound to have some enhancements - this does not mean they're faster, possibly just less buggy. I would use [ITopologicalOperator5](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/ITopologicalOperator_Interface/002m000003t6000000/) for this...

```
ITopologicalOperator5 pTopOp = (ITopologicalOperator5)PolygonFeature.ShapeCopy;
pTopOp.IsKnownSimple_2 = false;
pTopOp.Simplify();
IGeometry Left, Right;
pTopOp.Cut(NewPolyline,out Left,out Right);
```

Yes, it's not a set but it's still two features cut by a line. If you need a list then do something like:

```
List<IGeometry> GeomList = new List <IGeometry> ();
ITopologicalOperator5 pTopOp = (ITopologicalOperator5)PolygonFeature.ShapeCopy;
pTopOp.IsKnownSimple_2 = false;
pTopOp.Simplify();
IGeometry Left, Right;
pTopOp.Cut(NewPolyline,out Left,out Right);
GeomList.add(Left);
GeomList.add(Right);
```

then you can iterate through the list:

```
foreach (IGeometry ThisGeom in GeomList)
{
    // do something with the geometry ThisGeom
}
```

Inserting point:

```
// ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.IGeometry, ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.IPoint
private IGeometry InsertPointInPolygon(IGeometry InPoly, IPoint InsertPoint)
{
    // return just the input geometry if it's not a polygon...
    // polygons are made of rings, polylines are made from paths, so if it's not a
    // polygon there's going to be a type mismatch with the returned geometry.
    if (InPoly.GeometryType != esriGeometryType.esriGeometryPolygon) return InPoly;

    // We will need these later
    IGeometryCollection pGeomColl = InPoly as ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.IGeometryCollection;
    object MISSING = System.Type.Missing;

    // I will use IHitTest to find where on the geometry this point should fall
    IHitTest pHitTest = InPoly as ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.IHitTest;
    // IHitTest required variables:
    // the intialized values don't matter but if they're not set
    // you will have problems compiling the program
    double searchRadius = 0.001; // How far to seach, this one does matter
    IPoint hitPoint = new PointClass();
    double hitDist = 0;
    int hitPartIndex = 0; 
    int hitSegIndex = 0;
    bool hitRight = false;

    // HitTest gives the part and the segment that this point is closest to..
    // the return value is true if the hit test is successful
    if (pHitTest.HitTest(InsertPoint,searchRadius,esriGeometryHitPartType.esriGeometryPartBoundary, 
        hitPoint, ref hitDist, ref hitPartIndex,ref hitSegIndex, ref hitRight))
    {
        // create the new, empty polygon to put the rings in
        IGeometryCollection pOutGeom = new PolygonClass();

        // copy the parts (rings) into the new polygon
        for (int pPartCount = 0; pPartCount < pGeomColl.GeometryCount; pPartCount++)
        {
            // the hitpart is the segment that the point falls on
            if (pPartCount == hitPartIndex)
            { 
                // this is the one to modify
                IPointCollection pPointColl = pGeomColl.get_Geometry(pPartCount) as IPointCollection;
                IPointCollection pOutPointColl = new RingClass();
                for (int pPointCount = 0; pPointCount < pPointColl.PointCount; pPointCount++)
                {
                    pOutPointColl.AddPoint(pPointColl.get_Point(pPointCount), ref MISSING, ref MISSING);
                    if (pPointCount == hitSegIndex)
                    { 
                        // insert the new point here
                        pOutPointColl.AddPoint(InsertPoint, ref MISSING, ref MISSING);
                    }
                }
                // add the modified ring to the out geometry
                IRing pRing = pOutPointColl as IRing;
                pOutGeom.AddGeometry(pRing, ref MISSING, ref MISSING);
            }
            else
            { 
                // copy the unmodifed and unhit geometries
                pOutGeom.AddGeometry(pGeomColl.get_Geometry(pPartCount), ref MISSING, ref MISSING);
            }
        }
        // now pOutGeom contains all the rings..
        // make the geometry collection into a single geometry
        IGeometry pReturnGeometry = pOutGeom as IGeometry;
        pReturnGeometry.SpatialReference = InPoly.SpatialReference; // copy spatial reference
        return pReturnGeometry;
    }
    else
        return InPoly; // return the original geometry if the point doesn't intersect.



    return null; // if returning null then there's an error.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detail explain and after modified code the result is okay. I would like to ask one more question when add a vertex to adjacent polygon it is adding but a new segment is created from start point to newly added point. 'IPointCollection4 pPointCollection = new PolygonClass(); pPointCollection = PolygonFeature.Shape as IPointCollection4; object missing = Type.Missing; pPointCollection.AddPoint(InputPoint, ref missing, ref missing); PolygonFeature.Shape = pPointCollection; pFeatureCusor.UpdateFeature(PolygonFeature);'

Comment: Further explored help document that before, after is given as missing the point add last. How to add a point at specific segment.

Comment: In reality that is worthy of a new question. There is quite a lot to it. I will include some code here but if it doesn't explain it adequately then you will need to post a new question.